# What is the default height of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I thought this information would have been easier to find :-)

What is the default height of a UITableViewCell? It looks like 44 pixels, but I'd prefer to be sure.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

It's 44 pixels. Definitely. I'll never forget that number.

44px is also the default height for UIToolbar and UINavigationBar. (Both switch to 32px when autorotated to landscape orientation.)

Comment: Haha, "I'll never forget that number" sounds ominous ;-)

Comment: Does UIToolbar switch automatically? The UINavigationBar switched but I had to do it manually for the UIToolbar.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve this value programatically?

Comment: @antony: view.bounds.size.height

Comment: Does that value include the 1px separator?  That is, if finding the height of multiple rows combined, must one get rows*44+rows for the total height?

Comment: @MikeyWard: You probably figured this out already, but the 1px separator is included in the height. It actually covers the bottom-most content of the cell.

Comment: Technically, it's 44 points. It'll come out to 88px on a Retina display. Not to split hairs or anything.

Comment: @BenMosher I agree with you but the answer is from 2009. There were no retina display that year, so technically he "was" right. But not now.

Comment: I think using the constant - "UITableViewAutomaticDimension" is probably the best solution

Comment: @BenMosher It's come out to something higher than 88px on 4.7" and 5.5" screens. Not to split hairs or anything ;-)

Comment: Notched iPhones have a bigger default height, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54425101/4846592

Comment: Where do you find that design  ?

Answer (score 27):

If you want the default dimension on any device you can use: UITableViewAutomaticDimension

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Although 44 pixels is currently the default this is a useful method if your app relies on having the default value set.

Comment: Been renamed to `UITableView.automaticDimensions` in Swift 4

Comment: This only ever works if all you want is the default height.  If you actually want some multiple of the default height, then the value returned by this is not an actual height.  Apple have hidden the true point height behind this magic number (which happens to be -1).

Answer (score 16):

When `style = UITableViewStyleGrouped`, the default height of the top & bottom cells is actually `45.0f` (not `44.0f`). And, if the grouped table is only one row the cell height will be `46.0f`.

Comment: is that including the separator?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to calculate this on the fly, just allocate a dummy table cell and read off its height

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
int height = cell.frame.size.height ;
```

This way you defend against changes in future versions of iOS, although I suppose that is unlikely.

Comment: This is problematic with autolayout

Comment: Everything is problematic with autolayout.

Comment: problematic how, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift 4** and **Swift 5** simply use:

```
UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Using 44px won't suffice because it will vary with different screen pixel densities.

Answer (score 3):

"When style = UITableViewStyleGrouped, the default height of the top & bottom cells is actually 45.0f (not 44.0f). And, if the grouped table is only one row the cell height will be 46.0f."
It's wrong!! 44.0f in fact! I just test it!

Answer (score 2):

That sounds about right. But to be sure you could load up Interface builder, put in a UITableViewCell into the project then check the size properties in the Inspector window. I do not have my MacBook with me right now so I cannot check. But if you don't get a better answer from someone, that is how you can check for yourself.

Comment: Ah, okay, that is where I originally got the 44 from.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Somehow my iPhone XS had a strange configuration for this increased default height. After resetting the iPhone it reverted to the default 44pt.**

---

On iOS 12 the default height on iPhone X like devices (X, XS, XS Max, XR) is **49pt**.

Other devices on iOS 12 still have **44pt** as default.
It's a subtle difference, but it feels like a good improvement in direct comparison.

If you won't believe me, measure for yourself in this screenshot (don't forget to divide by 3)... ;)

[image]