# What's the default size for the UIImage in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I want to put a UIImage in the left side of each row in a UITableView. This is pretty standard, and is supported directly by UIKit. But putting in a (large) image causes all kinds of wonkiness, so presumably I'm supposed to scale the thing correctly myself. But none of the docs give a default size for this image using the standard out of the box views-- I'm surprised.

Others on SO indicate that 44 is the default height of a row ([What is the default height of UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594852/what-is-the-default-height-of-uitableviewcell)) Is 44x44 the "default" image size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

40x40

[UITableViewCell's imageView fit to 40x40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055495/uitableviewcells-imageview-fit-to-40x40)

> Need to make imageView filled in 40x40... I am using SDK 3.0 with build in "Cell Objects in Predefined Styles"...

Comment: In retina what would be size of image in tableviewcell? Is it 80*80?

Comment: @Dee yes it corresponds yo 80x80 in Retina

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Xcode 4.6.3 building for iOS 6.1. I tried 2 sizes of image assigned to `imageView` of the UITableViewCell: 48x48 and 128x128 pixels. This was run in the iOS Simulator (iPad).

In the UITableViewDelegate, I put the following line in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and put a break point right after it.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

In lldb, I get this output:

```
(lldb) po cell
$0 = 0x0751a720 <UITableViewCell: 0x751a720; frame = (0 88; 180 44); text = 'widget'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x751a6f0>>
(lldb) po cell.imageView
$1 = 0x0751a1e0 <UIImageView: 0x751a1e0; frame = (0 0; 43 43); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x751a1b0>>
```

The only conclusion I can reach based on this evidence is that the default image size is **not** 40x40.