# UITableView ImageView too large

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a little confused as to why my image isn't sized properly. I am passing in a 44x44 sized image to a `UITableView` with a default row height of 44 pixels, but I get the following result:

[image]

Is this not how I should be setting my `UITableViewCell` image?

```
 UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sent-indicator@2x.png"];         
 cell.imageView.image = imageOne;
```

Comment: As a note, for UIImage imageNamed, don't pass the @2x or the .png. It will assume png and make the retina/non-retina decision automatically.

Comment: @Apollo Hi! can you accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove @2x from name of image in code. The system find the retina image

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I'd run the app in the debugger, hit the "pause" button, and at the `(lldb)` prompt, type

   ```
   po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   ```

   That will produce a long cryptic log, but you can confirm the exact screen coordinates. I think you'll find the image view is 43 points high.

   ```
   (lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   <UIWindow: 0x8cb45e0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8cb1ca0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8cb2c70>>
      | <UITableView: 0x9031400; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8a950c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a92ed0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x8a95c10; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a95ce0>>
      |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8e9e1b0; frame = (0 440; 320 44); text = 'Row 10'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9d7b0>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8e9e890; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9eb20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9ea60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8e9d7e0; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9ee70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9d850>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8e9e340; frame = (73 0; 232 43.5); text = 'Row 10'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9e3e0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8e9e620; frame = (15 6; 43 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9d720>>
      |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x8e9fb60; frame = (73 43.5; 247 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9fbd0>>
      |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8e9d3f0; frame = (0 396; 320 44); text = 'Row 9'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9ca10>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8e9daf0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9dd80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9dcc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8e9ca40; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9e0d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9d580>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8e9d5b0; frame = (73 0; 232 43.5); text = 'Row 9'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9d650>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8e9d880; frame = (15 6; 43 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9c980>>
      |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x8e9fa70; frame = (73 43.5; 247 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9fae0>>
      |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8e9c620; frame = (0 352; 320 44); text = 'Row 8'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9bc50>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8e9cd30; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9cfc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9cf00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8e9bc80; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e9d310>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9c7b0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8e9c7e0; frame = (73 0; 232 43.5); text = 'Row 8'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9c880>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8e9cac0; frame = (15 6; 43 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9bbc0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x8e9f980; frame = (73 43.5; 247 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x8e9f9f0>>
   ```
2. By the way, that's 43 "points", not "pixels". You might want your `@2x` rendition to be 86 pixels high, not 43 pixels high. The non-`@2x` rendition can be 43 pixels high.

Answer (score 0):

The borders of the `UITableViewCell` are included in the default 44point height of the cell. This means that the default size of the cell's `imageView` property is actually 40x40 not 44x44 in order to accommodate these borders.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122183/740474

Answer (score 0):

when you specified @2x, you are specifying the image for retina displays which means a 44 x 44 image is actually treated as a 22 x 22 on the retina display. If your cell has a height of 44, then your image should be 88 pixels high.