# What is default icon size in UITableViewCell on iPhone, iPhone-retina and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, icons

I wrote library for using MimeTypes icons from GNOME themes on iOS ( https://github.com/darvin/UIImage-FileType ), and now I'm wondering: what is default icon size for inner image view in UITableViewCell in various iOS devices in pixels?

Comment: I use 40x40 as mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122167/whats-the-default-size-for-the-uiimage-in-a-uitableviewcell/2122183#2122183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594852/what-is-the-default-height-of-uitableviewcell), it's 44x44 points (88x88 pixels with the Retina screen).