# Since inserting UITableViewAutomaticDimension returned cells are tiny

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autoresize

I am working on a comment section for my app and want my cells to resize themselves automatically. If I replace `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`  with an arbitrary value like 120, it looks more or less like I want it to.

However, if I leave it at `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` the cells returned are literally tiny. I will add a picture at the end showing what both ways look like (left: UITableViewAutomaticDimension, right: rowHeight = 120). How can I fix this? I haven't found anyone with a similar problem since I *do* set the constraints, which were in many cases the cause of auto-resize problems (the subviews do have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`).

I am going to provide all the code which may be of interest. It's basically nothing else but a standard table view with cells which are supposed to auto-resize themselves and use constraints.

I would really appreciate your help!

### CommentCell

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {
    //all of these subviews have .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(profilePictureView)
    contentView.addSubview(usernameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(commentLabel)

    let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        profilePictureView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),
        profilePictureView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),
        profilePictureView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leftAnchor),
        profilePictureView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: -2),

        usernameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePictureView.rightAnchor, constant: 16),
        usernameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth - 66),
        usernameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePictureView.centerYAnchor, constant: -8),

        commentLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePictureView.rightAnchor, constant: 16),
        commentLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.widthAnchor),
        commentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4)
    ])
}
```

`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` | `120`:

[image: <code>UITableViewAutomaticDimension</code> | <code>120</code>]

Comment: I am pretty sure this has to do with the constraints. Is there a reason you don't do these in the storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is constraints - you add constraints to subviews of your cell, but not to contentView. You omitted height constraints for `usernameLabel` and `commentLabel` - thats correct, they will resize according to their contents. But `contentView` will not resize, because it doesn't know its desired size. Without any constraints, from which `contentView` might deduce its size, it defaults to `44.0`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594852/what-is-the-default-height-of-uitableviewcell).

So what you need to do is add top constraint to `usernameLabel` and bottom constraint to `commentLabel`

```
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0)
commentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
```

**edit**
You seem to already have top anchor, so just the bottom one should suffice.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. However, one doesn't need to set a `topAnchor` for the username label, for a topAnchor is set already with `centerYAnchor`.